# What should an API return if the operation can't be performed?

Tags: php, json, api, mobile, backend

I am writing an API in PHP for a mobile app. One of the endpoints, `create-user.php`, should be used to add new records to the User table. What if the application is trying to create a duplicate? I can catch this and return an error message (which, by the way?). The question is, should I also return a JSON with a structure like:

```
{
   "status": "The email already exists"
}
```

...to give the client more information about what went wrong? Or should I just use the error codes and that's it?

Comment: This is probably preferential. I would say use an error code. http://jsonapi.org/

Comment: The API *should* use applicable response codes.  The API *may* include any additional information you'd like in the response body.

Comment: As @David says. One thing i would add, is include the status code in the json as well, eg `{"response_code":400, "message":"Unable to create user - The email already exists"}` so if you later have to suppress http codes in headers (flash client anyone) the response is still available

Answer (score 4):

Return the http status 422 and an error message

> The 422 (Unprocessable Entity) status code means the server understands the content type of the request entity (hence a 415(Unsupported Media Type) status code is inappropriate), and the syntax of the request entity is correct (thus a 400 (Bad Request) status code is inappropriate) but was unable to process the contained instructions. For example, this error condition may occur if an XML request body contains well-formed (i.e., syntactically correct), but semantically erroneous, XML instructions.
>   page statistics

Concretely:

> 422 status code feels much more appropriate. The server understands what you're trying to do; and it understands the data that you're submitting; it simply won't let that data be processed.

Read more from Ben Nadel: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2434-http-status-codes-for-invalid-data-400-vs-422.htm

Further, the Laravel framework uses in it's Request Form class also the http status 422 by 'failed rules' (e.g. email already exists). See this: http://laravel.com/docs/master/validation

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return something to the user I would return a simple error like you have in your example, then I would also have a log file on the server that I would record the error, the inner exception, date and time and any other information you would want to know to debug.  That way if it is simple a duplicate the user can fix the issue and move on, but if they continually get the error you can look at the log file to find the real issue.